# add new constraint in next iteration in opl cplex

Tags: cplex, opl, flow-control

I am writing code in opl cplex.
I want to add new constraints like the following constraint to the model in each iteration;

```
x[1][2]==1.
```

How can I change the main block or post-processing? THANKYOU

Comment: Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooincremental.mod

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ emptyVar;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
 
 ctEmpty:0<=0;

}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
writeln("The minimum cost is ",costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30);
writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses and ",nbBus30," 30 seats buses ");
writeln();
}

main
{
thisOplModel.generate();

writeln("Basic model");

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

writeln("Let us add a row : saying that nbBus40 and nbBus30 should be equal");

thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus40,1);
thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus30,-1);
thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setBounds(0,0);
cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

writeln("Let us add a column : saying that nbBus50 could also be used and their cost is 700");
cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.emptyVar,700);
thisOplModel.ctKids.setCoef(thisOplModel.emptyVar,50);
cplex.solve();
writeln("The minimum cost is ",
thisOplModel.costBus40*thisOplModel.nbBus40.solutionValue  +thisOplModel.nbBus30.solutionValue*thisOplModel.costBus30
+700*thisOplModel.emptyVar.solutionValue);
writeln("We will use ",thisOplModel.nbBus40.solutionValue," 40 seats buses ",thisOplModel.nbBus30.solutionValue,
" 30 seats buses and "+thisOplModel.emptyVar.solutionValue," 50 seats buses");
}
```